# PHP preg_replace pattern inside curly brackets, but ignoring "flags" inside square brackets

Tags: php, regex, brackets

Given the following string:

```
Tags are inside {{ curvy }} brackets, but may also include {{ [f] flags }} in square brackets
```

I need to return just the "variables" - in this case "curvy" and "flags", while ignoring the flags.

I have 2 seperate regexs to achieve this, but I need the original string to remain unchanged, so I need to find a way to merge into a single regex which finds the variables, but ignores the flags.

Here are the two regexes I have now:

Grabs variables in {{ var }} --> `~\{\{\s+(.*?)\s+\}\}~`

Grabs flags [f] OR [fdc] --> `~/\[.*?\]/~`

The first regex works, but returns the variables with the flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\{\{(?:\s*\[[^][{}]*])?\s*(.*?)\s*\}\}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3zO9tr/1)

**Details**

- `\{\{` - `{{` substring
- `(?:\s*\[[^][{}]*])?` - an optional non-captuiring group matching 0+ whitespaces, `[`, any 0 or more chars other than `[`, `]`, `{` and `}` and then `]`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)`  - Group 1 capturing any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\}\}` - `}}` substring